# Symbol server for .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, symstore

I'm providing many NuGet packages of my application modules without pdb.
For debugging i'd like to use symbol server and store there binaries + pdb files.
What is the correct steps to make this possible?
1. Install Debugging Tools on Team City and all build agents
2. Create shared directory with UNC path (e.g. \MyPc\SymbolServer)
3. Add this path to '_NT_SYMBOL_PATH' environment variable on debugging clients
4. Use

```
symstore.exe add /r /g c:\app /f c:\app\bin\*.* /s \\MyPc\SymbolServer /t "My product" /v "x.x.x.x"
```

on build agent

No when somebody needs to debug some version of binary does it automatically download correct version of binary + pdb? Even if initial .exe path is differs from path on debugging client?
Now i'm debugging on a dev PC and i have another version of sources in my project (and on different dev PC sources path is differ) how can i debug code with exact version of sources?

Comment: you're already using NuGet, why not use [NuPeek](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/dmw/8356) for a combined NuGet and symbol server?

Comment: It isn't clear why you want to run your own symbol server. Push it to symbolsource.org instead: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package

Comment: i need my own symbol store

Comment: Symbol server functionality won't download any binary for you. When you build your project you determine which binaries you use (version + debug or release). The "symbol server functionality" kicks in when you start to debug, and at that time you have selected a version of you binary. Then what can only happen is if you don't have the matching pdb for that particular binary, VS tries to find the pdb using the available/configured symbol servers.

Comment: Question: can you package the pdb into your nuget packages?

Comment: "how can i debug code with exact version of sources"??? If the other dev machine has different version of sources then it means that he can build the matching pdbs for that source. Then those pdbs can be loaded. I cannot figure out what is going on at your end exactly. Something is messy.

Comment: I think it must clear: i have a team, which produce packages with some modules. and each member can use it development package of another member. This package shouldn't contain pdb files. I need: when somebody needs to debug foreign (owned by another member) package VS should download from our symbol server appropriate pdb files and ?somehow? revert/get appropriate revision of code from tfs to debug in source code.